# Using selenium how do I find location of a file / image relative to other content on a web page?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Python 3, selenium, and a chrome driver to move content from one forum platform to another. I have been able to use the driver.find_element_by methods to successfully find forum post title, poster name, post date, and post content and move it this content to another platform.

```
find_poster_names = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('PostName')
find_posts = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.entry-content.PostDetails')

dates = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.published.formatDate.formatDateTitle')
```

**My first question:**
Each forum post can have any number of replies.  When I run the above code for a web page with one forum post and n numbers of replies I get multiple lists of elements and can appropriately match up the elements (name, date, content) by position in the lists as every post/ reply has these items.  Yet, not all post / replies have files or images associated with them. So when I run the below code, I find the image / file elements but don't how to match them up with correct post / reply.  I have searched this website and only find question centered around finding images / files on the page but not their location relative to other content.

```
images = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('img')
files = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.dfLink.LTR')
```

**My second question:**
I can used the code to find the forum post content and use send keys to type the text in the new platform. Yet, is there a way to move the text to clipboard? I want to use the Control + V (paste function) for quicker run time. When I search I find posts about how to use clipboard in selenium but not how to get the content into clipboard when I find the text with this method.

```
find_posts = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.entry-content.PostDetails')
post_text = find_posts[n].text

create_post = 2nd_driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="threadsInGroup"]')
create_post.send_keys(post_text)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Comment: If you own the sites, seems like it would be easier to just export/convert the db content of site 1 into site 2 rather than scraping the pages with Selenium.

Comment: Thank you for the welcome!   I unfortunately don't own the sites. My job is switch platforms but I want to keep the content for searchable reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that you can use the .location method to find the location of a web element in relation to other web elements. Below you can see how I used it.

```
        for img in img_web_element_list:
            for post in find_reply_posts_web_elements:
                if img.location['y'] < post.location['y']:
                    img_post_loc.append(find_reply_posts_web_elements.index(post) - 1)
                    break
```